# How to implement reverse proxy?

Tags: php, daemon, reverse-proxy

I am working on creating a web application that acts as a load balancer, distributing requests made on the page to a number of servers and presenting the responses back to the user.  I've read a lot but I think my idea may be flawed, so I wanted some help.

The idea is to have a web form that uses `AJAX` and `PHP` to handle some arbitrary user input, then signal a daemon/process running on the server to process that request.  I'm not sure what language I would write the daemon in (ideas?).

The daemon in turn sends the request to the appropriate back-end server, and delivers the response back to the page.  The daemon would also allow back-end servers to establish outbound connections to the main server.

The main server would *hopefully* live on a VPS, but if necessary a dedicated server.  The back-end servers are already in existence.

---

**Is this a bad idea?** and if so **how can I improve my design?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i understand what exactly you need but try the following for the proxy (if you use apache). You might have to enable the proxy modules in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:80>
      ServerName mydomain.com
      ProxyRequests Off
      <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
      </Proxy>
      ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.4/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.4/
</VirtualHost>
```

You should find further details here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html

Language idea for the daemon? Why not using python. Python is a bit more memory efficient compared to PHP and got some cool stuff to create a daemon process.